# How to integrate a vector field in a triangle

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis, line-integrals

Consider the integral: $\int_S curl(F)n dS$ of the vector field $F(xy^2, yz^2, zx^2)$ over a triangle defined by the vertices $(1,0,0) $, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.

From Stokes' Theorem, this is the same as the line-integral defined by that triangle. Can I assume that is the same as the sum of the 3 line-integrals of each of the sides of the triangle?

Since each line is on one of the coordinate planes, this would really simplify the calculations.

Comment: The three integrals have the same value, by symmetry. Note that the orientation of the triangle, resp., of its boundary, has not been defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate the boundary of the triangle piecewise where each piece is in one coordinate plane. Just make sure you integrate each piece in the correct direction.